# how do I find the attribute with html "hidden" input with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am able to get element with a typical data:

```
<input id="mbb-offeringID-1" type="checkbox" name="offeringID.1" value="cLtX5MPovjIvCLvcPPMSjATUpzLHNW%2Bk9pGa3%2BTkldS92roGTDDM%2B8BvfXGJP5GWE3DNQLNkJUny6cgknOlP%2F3xEODHJiPzzb3Io7oXbgDNP9cSrVkoaA5JVvTc1IPb%2BEcbB%2BeqhE7BAczO81wFLlD3SbtD55y7hOIa5DYQLzkaI9FHJTuyAphRUriSbCRuS">
```

With

```
 page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
 title = soup.find('input', {'id': 'mbb-offeringID-1'}).get('value')
 print(title)
```

How do I retrive value with hidden input , an example is this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="offeringID.1" value="9Lt1oDtQ%2BIAdndBuUQBzl%2FXSUE8quGoqB41HEfz9IncLO4u3HybZ3EWtylW8vTJ1v3KZOS%2FPQRFGN6L0a0pjYFd8KcQ%2Bok3AsTNXxrQUaar1gXa7EHhACX2c%2Bh72E3izLUOwM4q6Wxw%3D">
```

Here's the full html

```
<div class="a-fixed-right-grid-col aod-atc-column a-col-right" style="width:150px;margin-right:-150px;float:left;">

   <form method="post" action="/gp/add-to-cart/html/ref=aod_dpdsk_new_0" class="aod-atc-form-header-desktop a-spacing-none">

        <input type="hidden" name="session-id" value="146-6039598-0678601">
          
        <input type="hidden" name="offeringID.1" value="9Lt1oDtQ%2BIAdndBuUQBzl%2FXSUE8quGoqB41HEfz9IncLO4u3HybZ3EWtylW8vTJ1v3KZOS%2FPQRFGN6L0a0pjYFd8KcQ%2Bok3AsTNXxrQUaar1gXa7EHhACX2c%2Bh72E3izLUOwM4q6Wxw%3D">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting hidden values from a form with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619802/extracting-hidden-values-from-a-form-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Thanks, how do I pass "name = offeringID,1" to it too and retrieve the value. It prints something else than I antipciated

Comment: I posted an answer here with slight modifications than the flagged answer since you want to add another keyword argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you also want to pass `"name = offeringID.1"` as a keyword argument to `find_all()` which I haven't covered in the answer I flagged as duplicated. I will post a solution here. You can add the `attrs=` argument:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("input", type="hidden", attrs={"name": "offeringID.1"}):
    print(tag["value"])
```

---

Edit: The data is loaded externally via Ajax, you get the "value" as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://www.amazon.ca/gp/aod/ajax/ref=auto_load_aod?asin=B07RF237B1&pc=dp",
}

params = (
    ("asin", "B07RF237B1"),
    ("pc", "dp"),
)

response = requests.get(
    "https://www.amazon.ca/gp/aod/ajax/ref=auto_load_aod",
    headers=headers,
    params=params,
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("input", type="hidden", attrs={"name": "offeringID.1"})["value"])
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me the same output as before.

Comment: @ShiO Can you share the URL and expected output

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/offer-listing/dp/B07RF237B1, I am trying to get the official amazon offerid output that's supposed to be the first one, usually

Comment: @ShiO I'm not sure what's the expected output. What is "offerid"?

Comment: I inspect the page with right click inspect on chrome and then paste the offeringID.1 in (ctrl f), the value regarding to the first offeringID should be the same in the question

Comment: Sorry the offeringID changes dynamically but often the value corresponding to the first offeringID.1 is the one that I want to get the output from

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I will do more research on ajax.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
hidden_tags = soup.find_all("input", type="hidden")
for tag in hidden_tags:
      print(tag )
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I pass "name = offeringID,1" to it too and retrieve the value